# Using S3 as a geowebcache blob store

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I'm having difficulty setting up an S3 bucket as a blobstore through geowebcache.

I have installed `geoserver 2.8.2` which has `gwc 1.8.1`

I am following the docs at http://geowebcache.org/docs/1.8.x/configuration/storage.html#amazon-simple-storage-service-s3-blob-store

My config for the blobstore (with names and keys removed):

```
  <backendTimeout>120</backendTimeout>
<blobStores>
    <S3BlobStore default="false">
        <id>S3Cache</id>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <bucket>bucketName</bucket>
        <prefix>gwc</prefix>
        <awsAccessKey>key</awsAccessKey>
        <awsSecretKey>secretkey</awsSecretKey>
        <maxConnections>50</maxConnections>
        <useHTTPS>true</useHTTPS>
        <useGzip>true</useGzip>
     </S3BlobStore>
</blobStores>
```

I have geoserver installed through `tomcat7` so when I restart the service and watch my geoserver logs I get the following error:

2016-03-02 07:56:22,294 INFO [config.XMLConfiguration] - Configuration file validated fine.

2016-03-02 07:56:22,381 WARN [support.DisposableBeanAdapter] - Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'geoServerLoader': java.lang.NullPointerException

2016-03-02 07:56:22,383 ERROR [context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'GeoSeverTileLayerCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-gwc-2.8.2.jar!/geowebcache-geoserver-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'gwcXmlConfig' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gwcXmlConfig' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-gwc-2.8.2.jar!/geowebcache-core-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: S3BlobStore : S3BlobStore

---- Debugging information ----

message             : S3BlobStore

cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException

cause-message       : S3BlobStore

class               : java.util.ArrayList

required-type       : java.util.ArrayList

converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter

class[1]            : org.geowebcache.config.GeoWebCacheConfiguration
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter

version : f22447f59ca37f72bfe6bc746d834b0e73e7c3fc/f22447f59ca37f72bfe6bc746d834b0e73e7c3fc

---

The error to myself looks like a module is missing, which it might be.  The documentation for the latest versions of `geoserver` and `gwc` indicated to me that s3BlobStore functionality is now included.  There used to be an s3 blob store community plugin, but I can't find the download for this, and it looked like this was simply a mod for the geoserver gui to setup an s3 blob where configuration could already be used.

Please could someone point me in the right direction, as to what I might be missing.

EDIT: I've installed `Geowebcache 1.8.1` as a standalone, and the config loads correctly and the s3 blob shows in the blobstores.  Now if the integrated geowebcache is different to the standalone, how can you get the s3 functionality included?

Comment: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GeoServer-2-8-GWC-S3-Plugin-td5252851.html

Comment: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/geoserver-gwc-s3-plugin-td5253778.html I'll download the plugin once available and close off question if it solves my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geoserver developer confirmed that there was an issue with the nightly build for the S3 plugin http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/geoserver-gwc-s3-plugin-td5253778.html

`gwc-S3-plugin` now available at http://ares.opengeo.org/geoserver/master/community-latest/

Downloaded, installed, and working as expected.